# iOS 5+ - freeze main thread execution while performing a request

Tags: ios, multithreading, rest, request

I'm implementing some RESTful APIs in a iOS app and I'm currently working on the login functionality. The user enters the username and the password, and when presses sign in this is what happens:

Network activity indicator becomes visible, text labels become hidden (as well as the sign in button), a activity indicator becomes visibile and a label with text "signing in". Then:

```
    dispatch_async(queue, 
    ^{[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performAuthCall) 
    withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];});
```

In the performAuthCall method, a view controller's property (a boolean) is set to YES or NO, depending if the login was successful or not (I use NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest). If it is, another view controller is being presented. If it's not, an alert is being shown.
I'm not really getting the result I was going for, the controller is testing the successful login boolean before the request has been performed, and I tried different approaches but I can't get it to work right and not freezing the UI. So, my question is:

How can I make all the hiding/showing stuff first (like making visible the activity indicator and the "Signing in" label), then begin the authorization process, wait until it is finished and only then segue to another view controller or display alerts or stuff?

Comment: dont block the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:::` instead

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
    //do the UI update/segue here once completed.
}];
```

This way you don't block the main thread during the url loading.

Answer (score 0):

To build upon Mike's answer about using background and to get the functionality I think you are looking for is to do the following.

Tie the action you have on click login button to activate a method.  This will still be in foreground.  Immediately dispatch to background your application logic to process message. Your background method (performAuthCall) can still run sync if you want.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0),
                       ^ {
                           [self performAuthCall];
                       });
```

Additionally in the same method you dispatched, set your bool to block calls, gray out your buttons, start your activity control.  The main thread can still function and do work, but your interception of items like shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier will allow you to block undesirable navigation away.

When your performAuthCall is done, have it perform a selector back on the main thread to set the bools so that methods can start moving, ungray items, stop the activity control.  It also determines whether you launch the alert (bad password) or force segue into your next controller.

Remember - everything the UI needs to be in main thread and all extra logic (like doing something like a login call) should be in background threads.